# WSO2 API Manager CPU graphs

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Wanted to understand what is this system load average parameter that is displayed under CPU metrics. How do we interpret it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be the load average in the CPU.

In case you're not familiar with it,

> CPU load average can be used to troubleshoot Tenable products'
>   performance issue. This metric can be collected by a debug, such as SC
>   debug sc-systeminfo.txt shows like this: Results of "uptime" are:
>
> 15:23:38 up 13 days, 8 min,  1 user,  load average: 3.84, 3.72, 2.41
>
> CPU load is the number of processes which are being executed by CPU or
>   waiting to be executed by CPU. So CPU load average is the average
>   number of processes being or waiting executed over past 1, 5 and 15
>   minutes. So the number shown above means:
>
> - load average over the last 1 minute is 3.84
> - load average over the last 5 minute is 3.72
>
>   - load average over the last 15 minute is 2.41

Ref: https://community.tenable.com/s/article/What-is-CPU-Load-Average